# Holomorphic function on an interval

Tags: complex-analysis

If $f(x),g(x)$  are holomorphic functions (both functions are everywhere defined) and we know that for $\alpha \in [a,b];f(\alpha)=g(\alpha)$, does this mean that $f(x)=g(x)$?

Comment: Identity principle, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_theorem.

Comment: Nit-pick: $[a, b]$ is a dubious notation when talking about complex numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. This is a particular case of the Identity Theorem, since an interval has accumulation points (actually, *all* of its points are accumulation points).